# Wordpress - wp.media upload limit

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way or parameters for wp.media function that can set the limit size of the upload files without editing .htaccess or wp-config file?

```
image_custom_uploader_file = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
    title: 'Choose File',
    button: {
          text: 'Choose File'
    },
    multiple: false
});
```

Comment: Would you consider making a change to your functions.php?

Comment: Did you got any ? success ?

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge two ways are there to set maximum limit for wp-media

method 1:
step a:->

just by adding the following code in theme’s functions.php file, you can increase the upload size:

@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );

@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');

@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );

step b:->
Create or Edit an existing PHP.INI file

In that file add the following code:

upload_max_filesize = 64M

post_max_size = 64M

max_execution_time = 300

This method is reported to work for many users. Remember if 64 doesn’t work, then try 10MB (sometimes that work).

step c:->

Edit the .htaccess file in your WordPress site’s root folder and add the following code:

php_value upload_max_filesize 64M

php_value post_max_size 64M

php_value max_execution_time 300

or,

method 2:
you can use the wp_handle_upload_prefilter that allows you to stop the uploading process if a specific condition is not accomplished.

try this code snippet:

function limit_upload_size( $file ) {

```
// Set the desired file size limit
$file_size_limit = 1024; // 1MB in KB

// exclude admins
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {

    $current_size = $file['size'];
    $current_size = $current_size / 1024; //get size in KB

    if ( $current_size > $file_size_limit ) {
        $file['error'] = sprintf( __( 'ERROR: File size limit is %d KB.' ), $file_size_limit );
    }

}
return $file;
```

}
add_filter ( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'limit_upload_size', 10, 1 );